# Why don't the answers appear at the end of the quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css

(NOT MY CODE)

I've been looking through some codes similar to the Pottermore sorting hat quiz as I'm trying to create my own and I came across this one:

https://codepen.io/akowtko/pen/mAZaKo

written by Nicole. It looks awesome but after the last question, the answers don't seem to pop up despite code being written in JavaScript to tabulate the score and churn out a "house". Can anyone tell me what went wrong with it? Thank you!

(I have a feeling it might have to do with the last part

```
function progressQuiz(){
  loadQuestion();
  loadAnswers();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  progressQuiz();      
})
```

but I'm not sure if that's the case and if it is how to fix it)

Comment: There are lot of things missing, like in `addAnswers()` function there is no object named `person`, also in `logAnswer()` function there is no variable named `houseName` which is actually assigned to `questionArea.innerHTML`. Check your code carefully that all the things are declared. Can you share the original code from where you've actually taken this?

Answer (score 0):

As Shahnawaz Hossan mentioned in his comment, there are several issues in the JavaScript. You can use your browser's web console to diagnose the errors.

At the end of the quiz (when you click an answer to the last question), in the web console you'll see something like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: person is not defined
  at addAnswers
  at logAnswer
```

In the `addAnswers` function, declare a variable named "person" and initialize it with an empty object:

```js
function addAnswers() {
  var person = {} // add before switch statement
  // ...
}
```

The object literal is required because the `house` property is added to it later in the function (otherwise you'll get a `TypeError`). You also want to return it:

```js
function addAnswers() {
  // ...
  return person.house // add to end of function
}
```

If you complete the quiz again, you'll get a new error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: houseName is not defined
  at logAnswer
```

In the `logAnswer` function, declare a variable named "houseName" and assign the result of invoking the `addAnswers` function:

```js
function logAnswer(i) {
  // ...
  if (current < allQuestions.length - 1) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // addAnswer() // remove this
    var houseName = addAnswers() // add this
    questionArea.innerHTML = houseName
    answerArea.innerHTML = ""
  }
}
```

Now, if you complete the quiz, you'll see the result of the quiz :)

---

Note that the above is only one approach and does not include any optimizations.